# SQLSRV Error on line 18

Tags: sqlsrv

I can't seem to figure out this error. I'm new to drupal and programming. For sqlsrv this error comes up whenever I go to my drupal site -> configurations.

Fatal error: Call to undefined method DatabaseSchema_mysql::EngineVersion() in C:\Users..\profiles\acquia\modules\sqlsrv\sqlsrv.install on line 18

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same issue. I wasn't running SQL Server either, so I removed:

Folder: docroot/profiles/acquia/modules/sqlsrv/sqlsrv
File:   docroot/profiles/acquia/modules/sqlsrv/sqlsrv.install

Make sure to take a full backup of your site beforehand. Clear cache, and visit the page when complete.

Hope this helps!